# Webpage testing on local machine

Tags: php, database-connection

I am trying to test my webpage files on my local machine.  My index page's url is as follows:  http://localhost:81/indexPage.php (I use port 81 instead of 80 since my database is on Wampserver).  Although I am able to access my database with phpmyadmin, when I open my index page in the browser, I get the following php error message:  "php_network_getaddresses: getaddrinfo failed: No such host is known"

What changes do I need to make in order for my page to access the DB?

Comment: I hope your loopback address (localhost) is working properly! Try `http://127.0.0.1:81/indexPage.php`

Comment: I work with WAMP server, and there's no reason that you HAVE to use port 81.  80 will likely make you jump through less hoops.

Comment: The web server is not the database! You don't even say what your DBMS is...

Comment: What code is issuing that error? Is there a line number in the error message? what code is at that line?

Answer (score 0):

I think you can add a port number where you make the connection to the database.